# how to check not nullable column s in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a data grid view i want to work some code if particular column is not null..so i given code like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
            If gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value IsNot System.DBNull.Value Then
                Dim cnt As Integer = RecordPresent("CompanyMaster_tbl", "CompanyName", gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
                If cnt = 0 Then
                    sqlInsertT1 = "Insert Into CompanyMaster_tbl(CompanyName) Values ('" + gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value + "')"
                    Exetransaction(sqlInsertT1)
                    Ccid = RecordID("Cid", "CompanyMaster_tbl", "CompanyName", gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
                Else
                    Ccid = RecordID("Cid", "CompanyMaster_tbl", "CompanyName", gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
                End If
            End If



            sqlInsertT2 = "Insert Into DepartmentMaster_tbl(dtname,dtphone,dtEmail,Cid) Values ('" + gv.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value + "','" + gv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value + "','" + gv.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value + "'," & Ccid & ");"
            Exetransaction(sqlInsertT2)
        Next
```

but some time this particular column null also if condition allow to execute the code written inside this condition
**If gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value IsNot System.DBNull.Value Then**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use `IsDBNull(Expression)` instead, And Check if it's empty string or not. Like this :

```
 If Not IsDBNull(gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value) AndAlso gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString.Length <> 0 Then
 ' YourCode
 End If
```